# SharePoint Hosted App secure content

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, ssl, browser-compatibility, https

I deployed a SharePoint Hosted App. 
When I use my App in my site through HTTPS, the browser (IE11) gives me the warning

> only secure content is displayed

How can I undestand which content in my App is not secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is causing the problem should be visible in your console, hit F12 to see developer tools, in your IE console you should see something like **"SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by..."** with the link to your insecure content.

You can also use other developer tools, such as Chrome developer tools, which will state something like **"[blocked] The page at ... ran insecure content from  ..."**.

Comment: I imagine this is [Open Sans font from Google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Open+Sans), and if you open the [CSS file there](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans) you can see it uses `@font-face` and `src` to the link you described